# JPA query in Spring Boot does not return any result

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2

I have created a pretty small and simple Spring Boot app using the H2 database and some JPA queries.

My controller is as follows:

```
package me.abhishek.springboot.microservice.example.todo.springbootmicroservicetodoservice;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ThingsToDoController {

    @Autowired
    ThingsToDoRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "Hello from the ToDo Controller\n";
    }

    @GetMapping("/todo/{name}")
    public ThingsToDo getThingsToDo(@PathVariable String name) {
        ThingsToDo thingToDo=repository.findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(name);

        return thingToDo;
    }
}
```

My bean is as follows:

```
package me.abhishek.springboot.microservice.example.todo.springbootmicroservicetodoservice;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="things_to_do")
public class ThingsToDo {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="verified")
    private int verificationStatus;

    private String task;

    public ThingsToDo() {

    }

    public ThingsToDo(Long id, String name, int verificationStatus, String task) {
        super();
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.verificationStatus=verificationStatus;
        this.task=task;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getVerificationStatus() {
        return verificationStatus;
    }

    public String getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ThingsToDo{" + 
                "id=" + id + 
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", verificationStatus='" + verificationStatus + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The H2 database schema is:

```
create table things_to_do
(
    id int,
    name varchar(500),
    verified boolean
);
```

And the queries that I run to insert values into the DB are:

```
insert into things_to_do (id, name, verified) values (1, 'Hello', 1);
insert into things_to_do (id, name, verified) values (2, 'Bye', 0);
```

However, when I do a get to `http://localhost:8080/todo/Hello`, it does not return any value to me; whereas it does output `Hello from the ToDo Controller` if I just ping `http://localhost:8080`.  Could someone please point out what step I am missing?  Thanks!

Edit:  From the logs (I didn't understand it much, though):

```
select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
Hibernate: select thingstodo0_.id as id1_0_, thingstodo0_.name as name2_0_, thingstodo0_.task as task3_0_, thingstodo0_.verified as verified4_0_ from things_to_do thingstodo0_ where upper(thingstodo0_.name) like upper(?)
```

Edit:

ThingsToDoRepository is as follows:

```
package me.abhishek.springboot.microservice.example.todo.springbootmicroservicetodoservice;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface ThingsToDoRepository extends JpaRepository<ThingsToDo, Long> {
    ThingsToDo findByNameIgnoreCaseContaining(String name);
}
```

Comment: @TwiN, by going to the console online.  Well, I do have `schema.sql` and `data.sql` but for some reason they are not run (I guess).

Comment: @TwiN, I have not tried that because I am anyway unable to get any result!

Comment: @TwiN, could you please confirm if my I am querying in the right way?  I am not sure when the constructor would be called and if that constructor would work as intended (because I don't have the column `task` in the table).

Comment: @TwiN, that's okay.  Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `update` in your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Because `H2` is an embedded database, Spring automatically sets the default value of `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` to `create-drop`, which overwrites your `schema.sql` and `data.sql`.

> Spring Boot chooses a default value for you based on
>   whether it thinks your database is embedded. It defaults to
>   create-drop if no schema manager has been detected or none in all
>   other cases.

[reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html)

Also, you should add `@Repository` at the top of your `ThingsToDoRepository` class.

Comment: thank you for all your help.  Your review of the code helped me a lot.  Thanks! :)